# Buscar palabras a través de letras en C

Tags: c

No consigo avanzar con el siguiente problema: Tengo que conseguir que se muestren por pantalla las palabras que contienen una letra introducida por el usuario.

Por ejemplo:

Entrada:

> Hola mundo, hoy es 26 de noviembre

El usuario introduce la letra: ***o***

El programa deberá imprimir:

> Hola mundo hoy noviembre

Pero si hubiese introducido: ***i***

Mostraría:

> noviembre

No tengo una gran propuesta de función pero mi idea es seguir el siguiente:

```
1. Si el carácter no es una letra del alfabeto avanza.
2. Es una letra.
    2.1 Dejar constancia en alguna variable que ahí empieza una palabra.
    2.2 Ir avanzado buscando si contiene esa letra.
        2.2.1 Si lo encuentra continuar hasta llegar al final marcarlo para luego imprimir desde el                 
              inicio hasta el final.
        2.2.2 No la encuentra avanza.
```

El **main** sobre el que trabajo es:

```
int main()
{
    char palabras [250];
    char letra;
    printf("Introduzca un texto de maximo 250 caracteres: \n");
    fgets(palabras, 250, stdin);
    printf("\n%s",palabras);
    printf("\nIntroduzca una letra: ");
    scanf(" %c", &letra);
    buscar(palabras, letra);
    return 0;
}
```

**La función sobre la que trabajo:**

```
//No funciona, no muestra nada simplemente acaba el programa: Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
void buscar(char palabras[250], char letra){
    int inicio, encontrado=0;
    for(int i=0; palabras[i]='\0'; i++){
       if(isalpha(palabras[i])){
          inicio=i;
          while(isalpha(palabras[i])&&encontrado==0){
               if(palabras[i]==letra)
                  encontrado=1;
               else i++;
         }
         if(encontrado==1){
           for(int j=inicio; j<=i; j++){
              printf("%c",palabras[j]);
              encontrado=0;
           }
         }
      }
    }
}
```

La verdad es que estoy muy perdida con esta función, si tenéis aunque sea un algoritmo mejor os agradecería que me lo contaseis.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes simplificar tu lógica de:

> 1. Si el carácter no es una letra del alfabeto avanza.
> 2. Es una letra.
>
>    1. Dejar constancia en alguna variable que ahí empieza una palabra.
>    2. Ir avanzado buscando si contiene esa letra.
>
>       1. Si lo encuentra continuar hasta llegar al final marcarlo para luego imprimir desde el inicio hasta el final.
>       2. No la encuentra avanza.

A

> 1. Leer el texto.
> 2. Separar el texto en palabras.
> 3. Si la palabra tiene la letra, mostrarla.

Podrías hacerlo así:

```
char texto[250] = {};
printf("Introduzca un texto de maximo 250 caracteres: \n");
fgets(texto, sizeof(texto), stdin);

char letra;
printf("\nIntroduzca una letra: ");
scanf(" %c", &letra);

// strtok separa un texto usando un separador, en este caso espacio
for (char *palabra = strtok(texto, " "); palabra; palabra = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
    // Por cada palabra, buscamos la letra.
    for (char *caracter = palabra; *caracter; ++caracter)
    {
        if (*caracter == letra)
        {
            // Si encontramos la letra, mostramos y dejamos de buscar.
            printf("%s\n", palabra);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVFNT4NAED2zv2KCqQFLTWvipVhvHkyqN0/Ww3RZ6KawW5fF1Db8dXFYCiLJhvl47828XT7LOG@aK6l4XiUCHkqbSH27e2TjkpEqa2tMKgsFShV8aZmE7Mw8vkMDVhytfr@7n3/ACs51zLwDUWwa@M/KGp1UJ45QqQ4HpFngURYaiAEcDXIrjCiXsFF@SOQ0E7YMHDiCUp6ETrsspJT2UwS6TM6FNTiat1H/JmIHWILTLTkqwsCE@xFcu45TSrWBwMndHDDHrUGyQa6t3vdb@K0CXLpD8Ad7fVuvO1TIPLqWsWbvkNCDwFCMYTrtY6I6ridTCEa0VeeibXf9we6kpCuLetnWI31bI3Dvwpq5UzMyaYStjIJ5zOqmeVLtc@RVRvvRc6wRXlDRtlGb8epbg9IF6dAPPispjAbk2iRoCsGQ/fA0x6xsZvQaK75Y/AI)</kbd>.

Comment: Muchasss graciasss!!!